# Google Actions with custom webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have built a small conversational bot using `API.AI` with Node.js as the back end. So every time a user makes a request it goes to my server and then from my server to API.Ai and it follows the same route with a response.

Now, I want to integrate it with Google Actions. But, `Google Actions` allows me to use `API.AI` as my webhook whereas I want `Google Actions` to talk to my `server`.

I have checked everywhere and can't find the correct process. Any, help will be appreciated in Integrating Actions with custom `webhook` instead of `API.API`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way it would work would be to have the Google servers for the Assistant talk to API.AI, and then API.AI would call your webhook. This lets API.AI do all of the natural language processing (NLP) and not have you attempt to write this part yourself to load into the Actions console.

Your API.AI project and your Action project need to be the same - if not, you can create a new Action project using the same project as API.AI, or you can export the contents of your API.AI project and import it into a new one.

Your API.AI project also needs to have the Actions on Google Integration turned on. From the left menu, select Integrations and then the Actions on Google tile and turn it on.

[image]

**However**

If you want to send things through your server, and then have your server call the [API.AI API](https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/) yourself, you can certainly do this. You would develop against the [Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/) and provide an `actions.json` file which describes the intents and webhook to use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I am curious is there a way to make actions in google talk with our server first sir.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your original question that this is what you're trying to do, or why you want to do this. However, I've updated the answer.